# SwiftUI: App crashes on activation of display after returning from the background

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, audio, swiftui

The app works just fine in the foreground. Animations work, audio plays without issues (even from notifications).
However, after the app moves into background, after a while, the app crashes with this error:

```
    Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS ()
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000016b45fff0
VM Region Info: 0x16b45fff0 is in 0x16b45c000-0x16b460000;  bytes after start: 16368  bytes before end: 15
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      CoreAnimation            11edd0000-11f860000 [ 10.6M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
      GAP OF 0x4bbfc000 BYTES
--->  STACK GUARD              16b45c000-16b460000 [   16K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  ... for thread 0
      Stack                    16b460000-16b55c000 [ 1008K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  thread 0

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [7134]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018d84f360 swift::MetadataCacheKey::operator==(swift::MetadataCacheKey) const + 4 (MetadataCache.h:457)
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018d84f5c0 std::__1::pair<swift::HashMapElementWrapper<(anonymous namespace)::GenericCacheEntry>*, unsigned int> swift::ConcurrentReadableHashMap<swift::HashMapElementWrapper<(anonymous namespace)::GenericCac... + 272 (MetadataCache.h:1439)
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018d841bd8 _swift_getGenericMetadata(swift::MetadataRequest, void const* const*, swift::TargetTypeContextDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*) + 380 (Concurrent.h:1001)
3   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018d822d00 __swift_instantiateCanonicalPrespecializedGenericMetadata + 36 (<compiler-generated>:0)
4   SwiftUI                         0x00000001909499a8 AnimatorBox.value(in:for:) + 140 (Animation.swift:167)
5   SwiftUI                         0x0000000190948454 AnyAnimator.value(in:for:) + 140 (Animation.swift:116)
6   SwiftUI                         0x00000001907d548c DefaultCombiningAnimator.value(in:for:) + 716 (DefaultCombiningAnimation.swift:26)
```

I personally think this is more related to the audio than any animation, however, the error stack is not really helpful. The other issue is, that I cannot say if the app crashes already in the background, or just when the display lights up, and the app prepares to return into the foreground.

Did anyone encounter this error? What causes it? Animation.swift is a system file, and I cannot backtrace the issue to my code.

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I will post an answer to this issue, as it may help someone in the future who has a similar issue.

As it turns out, the problem was indeed with the animations.

In most parts of my code I used the following instance method:

```
func animation(_ animation: Animation?) -> some View
```

Which btw. apparently will be deprecated in iOS 15. Source: Apple documentation

The problem was that every time the view was reloaded all the views got animated regardless if they should or not. My personal guess is that this was causing some concurrency issues in the background.

Anyways, the solution seams to be this

```
func animation<V>(_ animation: Animation?, value: V) -> some View where V : Equatable
```

Where value is:

> A value to monitor for changes.

Using this, if you configure the view properly, even when running in the background, views will get animated when the monitored value has changed.

I hope this will help someone. This definitely solved my problem!